# How to avoid generating too many empty tiles using GeoServer GWC generate PBF or PNG tiles

Tags: geowebcache

When I use GeoServer GWC generating PBF or PNG tiles, there are a lot of empty tiles. Causing by CentOS Inodes number is full, OS report an error:" No space left on device". I have to delete these empty tiles using commond: "find ./ -type f -size 0c|xargs -n 1 rm -f ". This is not a good solution. And It is not a good solution too if increase disk inodes number because too many inode use too much memory .Map tiles file number is so vast, for example 16 level have more than 100 million tiles,need 15GB memory. How I can avoid generating these vast empty tiles where I run GWC seed? Must I seek GeoServer GWC source code and compile? Have you met this problem?

Comment: why not just increase the number of inodes on the disk?

Comment: It is not a good solution too if increase disk inodes number because too many inode use too much memory .Map tiles file number is so vast, for example 16 level have more than 100 million tiles,need 15GB memory.

Comment: For png tiles you cant avoid generating the empty tiles because they are needed for a map without holes. For vector tiles you can limit generation of tiles to a lower zoom level, return all necessary data at that zoom level and overzoom those tiles at higher zoom levels if needed.